# Is it possible to join different unrelated query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

There is a project in which some samples are taken from the rows in the database and analyzed. A separate query is made for each column. (We are doing something outside of the normal use of the relational database. We are aware of this, but we need to somehow read this data here. There are several reasons for this.)

Due to the large number of queries, the need for optimization arose.
There are lots of queries as follow:

```
SELECT col1 FROM Table1 WHERE <some conditions>;
```

| col1 |
| --- |
| content11 |
| content12 |
| ... |

```
SELECT col2 FROM Table2 WHERE <some conditions>;
```

| col2 |
| --- |
| content21 |
| content22 |
| ... |

```
SELECT coln FROM Tablen WHERE <some conditions>;
...
```

| coln |
| --- |
| ... |

The results of these queries are input to an algorithm. I want to query queries as a single query without rules. The first thing that comes to my mind here is **UNION ALL**.

```
SELECT col1 FROM Table1 WHERE <some conditions>
UNION ALL
SELECT col2 FROM Table2 WHERE <some conditions>
```

But this query lists all results under one column.

| col1 |
| --- |
| content11 |
| content12 |
| ... |
| content21 |
| content22 |
| ... |

Is it possible to write a query that will result in the following?

| col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | col n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| content11 | content21 | ... | ... |  |
| content12 | content22 | ... | ... |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

> Although it is not suitable for relational database use, I want to combine the results of more than one query for various reasons. The main goal is to reduce the number of queries (thousands of queries are dropped). Instead of making query attacks to the database, it will reduce both performance and time costs with a small number of queries. We have a specific need here. We know this. Even so, the answers to be given will be an example of what can be done in the database.

Comment: Which column(s) maintain the relationship between the various column values?

Comment: There is no relationship between the columns. I just want to join the queries without rules and read the results.

Comment: What is your actual database?  You've tagged 4 different ones.

Comment: Because the same process is repeated on different types of databases. Firstly i want to do it for mssql and oracle

Comment: [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-with.html).

Comment: WITH creates a temporary table so it can be reused. But I want to combine different results with different headers.

Comment: "Vertical alignment" of two arbitrary datasets is entirely meaningless result in a relational database. Build a relationship on identifying columns (artificial ID or any real-world combination of attributes)

Comment: Yes, I realized from the answer given below that there is a need to create a relationship once in a while. I know I want the relational database to do something outside of the normal logic here. On the other hand, I was wondering if such a join can be done. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no natural relation between the rows of the different tables, you could perhaps zip them up using a generated `Row_Number()` value.

```
SELECT T1.col1, T2.col2, T3.col3, T4.col4
FROM (
    SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS rn FROM Table1
) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2) AS rn FROM Table2
) T2 ON T2.rn = T1.rn
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT col3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3) AS rn FROM Table3
) T3 ON T3.rn = COALESCE(T1.rn, T2.rn)
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT col4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col4) AS rn FROM Table4
) T4 ON T4.rn = COALESCE(T1.rn, T2.rn, T3.rn)
ORDER BY COALESCE(T1.rn, T2.rn, T3.rn, T4.rn)
```

The above allows for columns of different types. Obviously, the COALESCE() functions get increasing long.

If the values are all of the same data type, you can union the results and then feed them to a PIVOT. Something like:

```
SELECT PVT.col1, PVT.col2, PVT.col3, PVT.col4
FROM (
    SELECT 'col1' AS name, col1 AS val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS rn FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'col2' AS name, col2 AS val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2) AS rn FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'col3' AS name, col3 AS val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3) AS rn FROM Table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'col4' AS name, col4 AS val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col4) AS rn FROM Table4
) T
PIVOT (
    MAX(val)
    FOR name IN (col1, col2, col3, col4)
) PVT
ORDER BY PVT.rn
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FHddVf23) for a demo.

I expect you will also need to look into using dynamic SQL to generate your actual queries.

Comment: Thanks. If Table1,Table2,Table3 and TableN are all the same table, can I create an easier sql query?

Comment: @cguzel - Can you clarify your question? Otherwise my answer could be the trivial `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM Table1`. The above has been updated to correct the aliases used in the first select and to add a db<>fiddle link.

Comment: I can summarize as follows. Separate queries are made on n columns of n tables. Because there is a different where condition for each column.

Your answer is good. however, if it is to be solved with an easier query, I can group the columns and query for each table.

In short, if we had n queries for a single table, would you have a different suggestion?

Comment: There might be ways, but it would get complicated fast. You can play around with something like `SELECT CASE WHEN condition1a THEN col1a END AS col1a, CASE WHEN condition1b THEN col1b END AS col1b FROM Table1`, but you are then going to get a mix of null values to deal with. For the UNION case, you might be able to use a CROSS APPLY to select columns. Something like `SELECT A1.name, A1.val, ...AS rn FROM TABLE1 T1 CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'col1a' AS name, T1.col1a AS val WHERE T1.condition1a UNION ALL SELECT 'col1b' AS name, T1.col1b AS val WHERE T1.condition1b) A1 ...`  Messy and hard to read.